# Hibernate exception PropertyNotFoundException when using Transformer

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using hibernate and hql for querying in my Java codes. But I got an exception like this:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find setter for 0 on class [my class]
    at org.hibernate.property.ChainedPropertyAccessor.getSetter(ChainedPropertyAccessor.java:44)
```

I don't understand what the "0" means. Here are some deatils with examples:

I have several tables joining hql. The tables are like this:

```
A
- A_ID
- NAME

B
- B_ID
- A_ID

C
- C_ID
- B_ID
- LENGTH
- UNIT
```

Classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="A")
class A
{
    @Id
    @Column(name="A_ID", updatable=false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="NAME", nullable=false, length=10, updatable=false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="a", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="A_ID", nullable=false)
    private Set<B> bs;

    @Transient
    private Double length;

    @Transient
    private String unit;

    // Setters and getters
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="B")
class B
{
    @Id
    @Column(name="B_ID", updatable=false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="A_ID", nullable=false, insertable=true, updatable=false)
    private A a;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="b", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="B_ID", nullable=false)
    private Set<C> cs;

    // Setters and getters
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="C")
class C
{
    @Id
    @Column(name="C_ID", updatable=false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="B_ID", nullable=false, insertable=true, updatable=false)
    private B b;

    @Column(name="LENGTH", nullable=false, updatable=false)
    private Double length;

    @Column(name="UNIT", nullable=false, length=10, updatable=false)
    private String unit;

    // Setters and getters
    ...
}
```

hql:

```
select a, sum(c.length) as length, min(c.unit) as unit
from A a
left outer join a.b as b
left outer join b.c as c
group by
a.id
a.name
```

Query:

```
Query query = session.createQuery(hql.toString()).setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(A.class));
```

The result is a list of object "A" with the length and unit collected. I don't understand why I got this exception. Please give some advices.

---

Update:

I wrote a ResultTransformer and output all the "alias" to see the problem:

```
-> 0
-> length
-> unit
```

It seems it treats the "A" besides with length and unit. There should be some problems with my HQL?

Comment: have no setter and getter of table filed

Comment: Sorry, I have the getters and setters for the classes. I forgot to add them into the examples. So I think they are not the reason. 2 more questions: 1. Why the exception is "0"? 2. Do getters matter for this?

Comment: check table fileds and pojo's field are same?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I tried to use the generated SQL running against the DB directly and get the data correctly.

Comment: Problem found. Updates are in the content.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Problem found:

Even if the HQL can be translated to sql correctly, but when ResultTransformer gets the result, there will be only 3 fields in the result:

```
1. A
2. length
3. unit
```

No matter how many fields in A, they will be aggregated into a single field "A" and since I didn't set any alias to this field, it will be treated as "field 0".

So the problem solved after I changed the HQL like this:

```
select a.id as id, a.name as name, sum(c.length) as length, min(c.unit) as unit
from A a
left outer join a.b as b
left outer join b.c as c
group by
a.id
a.name
```

Comment: Finally answer that works! I used it in combination with
.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(MyClass.class)) 

to get list of beans.

Comment: I have a POJO class which has fields in camelCase, say 'discountDetail'. I have defined proper alias in my query i.e. `select discount_detail as discountDetail from Inventory where ...` but when hibernate returns the result set, it returns 'discountdetail' and thus I get an exception that setter for property 'discountdetail' not found. Any idea about this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

@Access(AccessType.FIELD)

add getter and setter of every field

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name="A")
    @Access(AccessType.FIELD)
    class A
    {
        @Id
        @Column(name="A_ID", updatable=false)
        private Long id;

       public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id= id;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have setters and getters for all the fields. Sorry, I didn't mention that in the code. The code has been updated. What does it mean by adding "@Access(AccessType.FIELD)"?

Comment: When placed on a field or property getter @Access can specify that the default should be overridden for this field.

Comment: Field Access with @Accesstype in Hibernate using "@Access(AccessType.FIELD)"

Comment: Thank you. The problem is still there and I don't understand why there is a "0" in that exception...