# HQL related: How to create an ailias to an object instead a field

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

This is a related question to another question:

[Hibernate exception PropertyNotFoundException when using Transformer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13834777/hibernate-exception-propertynotfoundexception-when-using-transformer)

I have several tables joining hql. The tables are like this:

```
A
- A_ID
- NAME

B
- B_ID
- A_ID

C
- C_ID
- B_ID
- LENGTH
- UNIT
```

Classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="A")
class A
{
    @Id
    @Column(name="A_ID", updatable=false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="NAME", nullable=false, length=10, updatable=false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="a", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="A_ID", nullable=false)
    private Set<B> bs;

    // Setters and getters
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="B")
class B
{
    @Id
    @Column(name="B_ID", updatable=false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="A_ID", nullable=false, insertable=true, updatable=false)
    private A a;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="b", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="B_ID", nullable=false)
    private Set<C> cs;

    @Transient
    private Double length;

    @Transient
    private String unit;

    // Setters and getters
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="C")
class C
{
    @Id
    @Column(name="C_ID", updatable=false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="B_ID", nullable=false, insertable=true, updatable=false)
    private B b;

    @Column(name="LENGTH", nullable=false, updatable=false)
    private Double length;

    @Column(name="UNIT", nullable=false, length=10, updatable=false)
    private String unit;

    // Setters and getters
    ...
}
```

After solving that issue, it is like this now:

```
select b.id as id, sum(c.length) as length, min(c.unit) as unit
from B b
left outer join b.c as c
group by b.id
```

Now the problem is:

I don't know how to set the alias of A in the returned B object in the HQL. This is causing a NPE when I'm doing this:

```
b.getA().getName();
```

Because I don't know how to set the related object "A" with "B" since there is only an ID in the B table.

Please help. Thank you very much.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by alias here? I'm sorry but I don't understand clearly...

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. The "alias" here means the mapping from the "A" object to the field in "B" object. I can't put the A in the "select" part since it is not in the "group by" condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b.getA().getName();` This will throw a NPE because `select b.id as id, sum(c.length) as length, min(c.unit) as unit from B b` does not include `A`. When you use the select clause in a HQL query it will only return the fields mentioned.

Please refer to http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html for more information.

EDIT:

If you read through the documentation provided you would have see `select cat.mate from Cat cat`. This can be incorporated to your query. Add `b.A` in your select clause and it should work.

EDIT:

If `select b.id as id, sum(c.length) as length, min(c.unit) as unit
from B b
left outer join b.c as c
group by b.id`
work then
`select b.id as id, sum(c.length) as length, min(c.unit) as unit, b.A
from B b
left outer join b.c as c
group by b.id, b.A`
should as well.

Comment: Yes, I know the reason. But I don't know how to "mention" the A in the HQL. I will read the doc you provide and it will be appreciated if you can tell me how to modify the hql. Thank you!

Comment: Actually I have read that doc many times but I still don't know how to do it.

Comment: Putting the "b.A" into the select clause won't help since I have a "group by" clause which requires me to put all the fields in the select clause there.

Comment: My HQL and SQL are rusty at best so whats wrong with with adding b.A to group by?

Comment: Haha, I know you will ask about this. Here is the thing:
1. If you put the b.A into the select clause, it will aromatically add all of the fields of A into the select clause when parsing the hql to sql.

2. If you put the b.A into the group by clause, it will only add a.id into the group by clause when parsing it.

So this means the fields in the select clause are more than the fields in the group by. The sql translated is not correct and can't be used.

Comment: Yes I get that, I'm asking why you can't add `b.A` to your `Group By` clause.

Comment: yes, I can but it won't help. The sql translated from the HQL is not correct.

Comment: That is a bit hard to believe. If your Hibernate version is an stable one it should be translated properly...

Comment: Actually I have the "b.a" in the group by in my HQL but I don't know how to use it. So I didn't write that in the example to see more ideas.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21064/discussion-between-thihara-and-xiezi)