# org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find setter for 0

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I'm fetching only selected attributes from a table using HQL, maintaining a list of non-entity class objects.
For Eg. My entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="STUDENT")
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="NAME", columnDefinition="TEXT", length="60", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Dept_id", nullable = false)
    private Department department;

    // Other fields...
    // Getter-Setters
}
```

and non-persistent DTO class is having only fewer class members (say, name only):

```
public class StudentDTO {
    private String name;
    // Getter-Setter for name
}
```

Now using

```
public List<StudentDTO> getStudents(Long deptId) {
    List<StudentDTO> students;

    Query query = session.createQuery("select student.name " +
            "from Student as student " +
            "where Dept_id =?").setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(StudentDTO.class));
    query.setString(0, Long.toString(deptId));

    students = CommonUtil.castList(StudentDTO.class, query.list()); 
    return students;
}
```

where castList converts any collection into ArrayList.

```
public static <T> List<T> castList(Class<? extends T> clazz, Collection<?> c) {
            List<T> resultList = new ArrayList<T>(c.size());
            for(Object o: c)
              resultList.add(clazz.cast(o));
            return resultList;
        }
```

throws **org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find setter for 0 on class ../StudentDTO**

Referring [Hibernate exception PropertyNotFoundException when using Transformer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13834777/hibernate-exception-propertynotfoundexception-when-using-transformer), I changed my query to `"select student.id as id,..."`, having `Long id` inside `StudentDTO` but that throw same exception, saying setter not found for 1.

Getter/Setters are given for each property. Please suggest changes!

Comment: The obvious problem is the missing aliases.  Try "select student.name as name"

Comment: Also, can you post the full stack?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As you are using `AliasToBeanResultTransformer`, you have to declare proper `alias` names in your `query`. The class name itself says that it will transform the results into your `resultClass` using the `alias` names.

The `transformTuple` method of `AliasToBeanResultTransformer` class uses the `alias` names to find the setter methods of your `resultClass (StudentDto)`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < aliases.length; i++) {
                    String alias = aliases[i];
                    if(alias != null) {
                        setters[i] = propertyAccessor.getSetter(resultClass, alias);
                    }
                }
```

In order to make `AliasToBeanResultTransformer` work properly you need to use proper alias names in your `query`. If the property name in your `StudentDto` class is `name`, you should use `select student.name as name`. Using `select student.name as n` will again throw exception. The `alias` names that you are using in the `query` should be same as the property names in your DTO class.

Answer (score 5):

just write each column name as below :
Select column_name as property_name , ...., from Class_name

> eg: select student.name **as name** from Student

Answer (score 4):

set alias for each field in select clause, these field is same as filed name in your persistence class which you set as transformer class in your query, for example:

```
 public mypersistenceclass()
    {
    // define constructor
    public mypersistenceclass(){}

       private String username;
    // define setter and getter

 }

  public userclass()
  {
  ...
     Query query = session.createQuery("select Users.username as username ...")
      .setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(mypersistenceclass.class));

  ...
  }
```